# ACL which supports MySQL in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, security, acl, backend

I am using Node.js with MySQL. Is there an ACL library in npm which supports node.js with MySQL? I did not find answers to similar questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

It's a a node based simple ACL system
https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl.
For its back-end you can use Sequelize
https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl-sequelize. 
Also node-acl recommend node-acl-knex but they are not currently support mysql